# How can I change the <a href"" onclick of another Image with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a script to change the img src displayed in a div (main_view) when the image in another div (gallery) is clicked:

**JS**

```
//Swap Image on Click
   $("ul.thumb li a").click(function() {
    var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); //Find Image Name
    $("#main_view img").attr({ src: mainImage });
    return false;
   });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="gallery">
  <ul class="thumb">
    <li><a href="images/childrentxt.png"><img src="images/buttons/kids.png"
         title="children.htm" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/martialartstxt.png"><img src="images/buttons/dee.png"
         title="mma.htm" /></a></li>   
    <li><a href="images/cardiotxt.png"><img src="images/buttons/cardio.png"
         title="fitness.htm" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/combattxt.png"><img src="images/buttons/tristan.png"
         title="combat.htm" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="main_view">
    <a href="fitness.htm" title="Mixed Martial Arts" target="_self">
    <img src="images/maintxt.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

I would then like to allow the user to click the image displayed in the main_view div to navigate to the page associated with that image.

I'm new to jquery and js and have not been successful in writing script to do this.

Currently the "main_view's img src" is found in the "gallery's a href".  I've been trying  to use the "gallery img title" to store the value to be used to update the "main_view a href" onclick.  Can someone please HELP me??

Thanks,
Tracey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I wouldn't recommend using the `title` attribute to store the `href`. Title is meant for something else. Instead, a better attribute would be `rel`.

So, here's how I would do it. I would change the `title` attribute to `rel` and then add a `title` attribute with the image title.

```
<div id="gallery">
  <ul class="thumb">
    <li><a href="images/childrentxt.png"><img src="images/buttons/kids.png"
         rel="children.htm" title="Name of image 1" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/martialartstxt.png"><img src="images/buttons/dee.png"
         rel="mma.htm" title="Name of image 2" /></a></li>   
    <li><a href="images/cardiotxt.png"><img src="images/buttons/cardio.png"
         rel="fitness.htm" title="Name of image 3" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/combattxt.png"><img src="images/buttons/tristan.png"
         rel="combat.htm" title="Name of image 4" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="main_view">
    <a href="fitness.htm" title="Mixed Martial Arts" target="_self">
    <img src="images/maintxt.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

And now the JS:

```
$("ul.thumb li a").click(function() {
    var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); // Find Image URL
    var imgLink = $(this).children('img').attr('rel'); // Find the image link in rel
    var imgTitle = $(this).children('img').attr('title'); // Find the image title
    $("#main_view").html('<a href="' + imgLink + '" title="' + imgTitle + '" target="_self"><img src="' + mainImage + '" alt="" /></a>');
    return false;
});
```

So, instead of just changing the img src, I just populate the entire `#main_view` div. I've also grabbed the image title from the image tag.

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: you can just use `this.href`, `this.title` for the `<a>` tag. ;)

Comment: Thanks sooo much!  You make it look so easy!  I really appreciate the tip about using the "rel" tag instead of the "title" tag.

Comment: It would be great if this worked to up vote and accept the answer :)

Comment: Your answer worked for me and I clicked the "check"  icon but I'm not able to click the "up vote" icon since this was my first time using this site  :(   I get a message indicating I have to have a reputation over 15 to vote...   But I'm truly appreciative!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("ul.thumb li a").click(function() {
    $("#main_view img").attr('src', $(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
   });
```

or get rid of the a href altogether and tie the click to the image

```
 $("ul.thumb li img").click(function() {
    $("#main_view img").attr('src', $(this).attr("title"));
    return false;
   });
```

Comment: what was wrong with OPs original approach passing over a `map` object ? It's basically the same code you're suggesting